# PHP | Error when sending JSON POST to API URL

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to send JSON to an API url. I am sending the json from `test.php` and I am receiving the data from `api.php`. I want to log the data into a text file, but nothing is logged, I assume that $data is returning null? In my `test.php` file it keeps returning "Sent BAD, request terminated." What am I doing wrong? How would I fix this?

test.php

```php
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$array = array('foo' => 'bar');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://dropchat.net/api.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($array));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

if ($server_output == "OK") { 
    echo "Sent OK";
} else { 
    echo "Sent BAD, request terminated.";
}

?>
```

api.php

```php
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$fp = fopen("myText.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: `I assume`...don't assume, test. And configure PHP to log errors and warnings to a file.

Comment: `if ($server_output == "OK") { ` will never be `true` because api.php doesn't echo "OK" (or anything else, for that matter). So that doesn't prove anything one way or another.

Comment: Should `test.php` be `api.php`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I will fix that

Comment: The 2nd argument to `fwrite()` should be a string. `$data` is an array.

Comment: I meant here: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://dropchat.net/test.php");`

Comment: `api.php` doens't output anything, why do you expect `$server_output` to contain `OK`?

Comment: `api.php` needs error checking. If it's successful it should `echo 'OK'`.

Comment: @Barmar It creates the file, but it is empty.

Comment: You **still** haven't fixed the URL in `curl_setopt`.

Comment: @Barmar It has been fixed now. I thought json_decode made a PHP array into a string once it has been json encoded?

Comment: `json_encode()` makes an array into a string. `json_decode()` makes a string into an array or object.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` returns a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add error checking to `api.php` so you'll know what happened.

You can't write an array to a file, you can only write a string. So write the `foo` element of the array.

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if ($data === null) {
    echo json_last_error_msg();
} else {
    file_put_contents("myText.txt", $data['foo']);
    echo "OK";
?>
```

Then change the caller to print the error message:

```
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

if ($server_output == "OK") { 
    echo "Sent OK";
} else { 
    echo "Sent BAD, reason: $server_output";
}
```